# File Upload to S3 through Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im failing to upload file in S3. Im using a ajax call as below,

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file",file_input.files[0])

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.ap-xxxx-2.amazonaws.com/xxx/xxx",
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        headers: { "X-API-KEY": apikey},
        contentType: false,
        processType: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data['result'] === "true")
            {
                $('#issue-error').text('Your report has been submitted successfully.');
                $('#issue-error').css('color','green').show();
                $('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
            }
        },
    });
```

Here, the URL is AWS API with lamda function written in Python. Im failing in passing file parameter itself. Normal parameters i can POST, but not a file.

I need help on this. Thanks

Comment: How do you create signed URL and what is the error?

Comment: I have AWS Account and created a APIKey for authorized API Call. The error is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400."

Comment: Oh okay, you need to configure your S3 bucket. Search over it. It is pretty straight forward. I am submitting sample doc below as an answer.

Comment: I can call a Python Function and upload a file. But if i do same from ajax, im facing this error. What kind of configuration is need in S3?

Comment: It is basically a domain restriction, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html. You need to remove domain restriction.

Comment: This is my S3 cors config. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>*</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Put this in your bucket configuration in S3.

Comment: My present config is same as above.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use the aws javascript sdk for uploading files to aws,

```
   AWS.config.credentials = { accessKeyId: "xxxxxxxxxx", secretAccessKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" }
      AWS.config.region = 'us-west-2';          
      var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucket-name/folder-name'}});
        var file = fileChooser.files[0];
        if (file) {              
          var params = {
            Key: "example.png",
            ContentType: file.type,
            Metadata: {
              "security-key": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
            } ,
            Body: file
            };
            bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
              console.log("file uploaded successfully");                  
            });
        } else {
        }
```